# Make Rows with large data set in Jade Templating in Node.js

Tags: node.js, pug

I have about 100 items that I use [jade iteration](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#iteration) to write each one of them to html. However, I'm struggling to find an elegant way to separate the items into rows of three.

To be clear, I want something like this:

```
.row
    .item1
    .item2
    .item3
.row
    .item1
```

... and so on...

I've tried things with inline javascript like this with no luck:

```
- var a = 0;
  each item in list
    - a++;
    - if(a % 3 == 0)
      .row-fluid
        .span3(id='#{item.id}')
          p #{item.id}
    - else
        .span3(id='#{item.id}')
          p #{item.id}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- var i = -3;
while i <= list.length
  - i += 3;
  .row
    each item in list.slice(i, i+3)
      .span3(id='#{item.id}')
```

Answer (score 2):

note: this kills the list

```
while list.length > 0
  .row
    for item in list.splice(0, 3)
      .span3(id=item.id)
        p= item.id
```

let me know if this works as i just wrote it off the top of my head

Comment: This doesn't work. I like the splice id, but I get an error: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined. When I use while list.id != undefined, then I don't get an error, but nothing prints to the screen.

Comment: I'll give you a point for sending me in the right direction. Thanks!